# sign operations on limits tending to minus infinity

Tags: limits

I dont really understand how should I calculate limists tending to minus infinity in case of signs. Here is example that is already solved:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x-3}{\color{red}{|x|}\sqrt{1-\frac{9}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x-3}{\color{red}{-x}\sqrt{1-\frac{9}{x^2}}}=-1$

why $x^2$ after exiting the square root, it gets an absolute value which later turns into $-x$. why also when dividing the content of the root by $x^2$, the values do not change in terms of sign into: $\sqrt{x^2(-1+\frac{9}{x^2})}$. Can you tell me where i should learn this from? Does it have exact name?

Comment: When considering limits as $x\to-\infty$, you can restrict to $x<0$ (and better here: to $x<-3$, to avoid  denominator $=0$). Now,$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\ge0\\-x&\text{if }x\le0\end{cases}.$$On the other hand, for every $x\ne0,$
$$\frac{x^2-9}{x^2}=\frac{x^2}{x^2}-\frac9{x^2}=1-\frac9{x^2}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval seems clear I think, I should always look on case where my square would give me negative value by restriction

Comment: Does my comment answer your 2 questions? I am not sure to understand yours. The values of $x^2$ and $|x|$ are  never negative. If $x$ itself is negative then $|x|=-x>0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thats true, I mean $x^2$ have two cases - where numbers multipled are both positive or negative but my restriction in that limit makes me choose second case so I should add "-" sign before absoulte value

Comment: No, you should not 'add "-" sign before absoulte value'. You should add it when you *remove* the absolute value.

Comment: sorry for my english but I try explain it as best I can

Comment: OK, now is fine. thank